# How to have one user define when a button appears for other users

Tags: javascript, apache2

I have a custom polling app that people take while on a webcast. The administrator of the poll wants to be able to determine when they go to the next question. I can either have the new poll page pushed or have a button appear that says "Next Question".

Is this likely a long-polling thing? Or just a short-polling? Most of these users are in large corporations and using IE 7 or 8. I am considering:

Admin clicks button that puts a key in memcached "permit_next:{$question_id}"
User side has a poll running that checks a page that checks that memcache, if exists and is true, then it displays the question button

I'm worried about having 30-100 long polls running though. The server usually handles 10-20 simultaneous requests fine, but I don't want to lock up 100 Apache processes waiting.

Anyone tackle this before, or see an example on a page you remember and I could investigate?

TIA,
Hans

Comment: If you are worried about your web server handling 100 requests every couple of minutes then you have something wrong with your web server... a server should be able to handle 1000s of requests every second.

Comment: I am worried about it holding open 100 requests, as in long-polling, or 100 hits/second as it short polls for 1-10 minutes (as they talk about the results of the last poll). And, to be honest I have no idea how many hits it can take every second and it's so dependent on the server hardware that it's tough to answer without actually experiencing it. I'm just trying to prevent thinking it will work fine and then have it not.

Comment: As I said, stop worrying - Your server should be fine.  Solve the problem and then optimize.  This should be a non-issue.

Comment: Yeah, I did end up just going with short polling and we'll see what happens. I went outside my CI framework and just connect to a memcache server (local, not network) and there aren't any includes. It's about as fast as PHP is going to get and I can do an ab -c 40 -n 1000 in no time (almost literally).